# Set difference in relational calculus

Tags: database, logic, relational-database, relational-algebra

Given this schema:

```
Musicians(ssn, name, annualIncome)
Instruments(instrID, iname, key)
Plays(ssn, instrID)
```

In relational calculus, I am to find the instrId played only by musicians whose name is ‘Andrew’,
i.e., are not played by any musician with any other name.

I've come up with the following:

```
{T1.instrID | ∃T1 ∈ Plays ¬(∃P2 ∈ Plays (P2.name =/ 'Andrew' AND P1.name /= 'Andrew' ))}
```

where `'=/'` is `'not equal'`

Is it correct?

Comment: Please explain why you think it is correct. PS What is the column of the result called? PPS Google 'unicode not equal' & 'unicode relational algebra'. (Beware that not all unusual character ranges are in SO or default fonts.)

Answer (score 2):

(1) find the instruments played by anyone not named andrew 
(2) subtract that from the set of all instruments (***).

("subtract that" in calculus is SUCH THAT NOT EXISTS ...)

You *should* have noticed that your solution cannot possibly be correct, because there is no reference what so ever to "named andrew", which is like a crucial part of the problem specification.

(***) it is rather unclear from the problem specification whether instruments that are not played at all (by anyone) should appear in the result.  Depending on the answer, it might have to be "from the set of instruments that are played by at least one player".

Comment: No, not really (I mean no I'm not really going to take a look).  This is not www.i_want_to_be_spoonfed_the_solution.com.  I gave some hints and I think they should be sufficient.